# Can anyone give me a hint how to start this problem?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $P(X \leq 0)=0$ and let $\mu =E(X)$ exist. Show that $P(X \geq 2\mu) ≤ \frac{1}{2}$. I don't really know how to start this one... so any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Or $\Pr(X\ge15\mu)\le\dfrac 1 {15}$, i.e. people having at least $15$ times the average income cannot be more than $1/15$ of the population (assuming incomes are never negative).  That's Markov's inequality (except that Markov's inequality also allows other numbers than $15$, namely all positive numbers). ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(X\ge \alpha) > \frac12$ then
$$E(X) = \int_0^\infty x\ \mathrm d P_X \ge \int_\alpha^\infty x \ \mathrm d P_X \ge \alpha \int_\alpha^\infty \ \mathrm dP_X = \alpha P(X\ge \alpha) > \frac\alpha2$$
Now use contradiction.

Here $P_X$ is the probability measure of $X$ defined by $P_X(A) := P(X\in A)$ for $A\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For all $t \geq 0$ the inequality $X \geq t\,1_{X \geq t}$ holds almost surely.

Comment: Where do you use $P(X\le 0) = 0$? Without this assumption, it's false.

Comment: @AlexR: I edited my answer since the OP was only asking for hints. What we really need is $E(X \, 1_{X \leq 2\mu}) \geq 0$, which is implied by $P(X \leq 0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what E(x) means and how many values of X are above and below u.

Answer (score -2):

$P(X \geq 2\mu) = P\left(z \geq \dfrac{2\mu-\mu}{\sigma}\right)= P\left(z\geq \dfrac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)$, but $P(X \leq 0) = 0 \Rightarrow P\left(z \leq \dfrac{0-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = 0 \Rightarrow P\left(z \geq \dfrac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) = P\left(z \leq -\dfrac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) = 0 \leq \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: thank you very much, BRIC-Fan

Comment: No problem, @kopara.....

Comment: I think here you are assuming that $X$ is normally distributed. I don't see that anywhere in the problem.

Comment: The inequalities here are false for a general probability distribution $P$, the question however asks for the general case.

Comment: @kopara You might want to reconsider other answers or re-phrase your question, since this one is actually flawed for the general case.